# Is there a way to generate a Braintree token without having to add a PHP script to my server?

Tags: javascript, php, e-commerce, braintree

Currently, my Javascript/jQuery has to do the following in order to generate a nonce to be used with my payment forms with Braintree:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $.get('http://me.com/braintree/gen-token.php',{},function(sData) {
    var clientToken = $.trim(sData);
    braintree.setup(clientToken, 'custom', {id:'checkout'});    
  });
});

</script>
```

This requires that I do an extra step on my server to create that token:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

require_once('braintree/lib/Braintree.php');

// change me whether live or not
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox'); 
// change the next three
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('4444hjxm5h27zxdb');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('444443c8qcf2wq5p');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('4444b76e4bbf8a6f03cb7ace0e812ba');

echo($clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate());
```

Is there a way I can skip the server step for that nonce?

EDIT: Yes, I can also add this code to the top of the form page in the PHP section (before HTML is displayed) and have it set the token via `<?= $clientToken ?>`. That's another way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/authorization/tokenization-key/javascript/v2

You login to your Braintree Dashboard, then go to Account > My User > View Authorizations > Tokenization Keys, and click Generate New Tokenization Key. This will give you a hard-coded one. You can then switch your code like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function invalidForm(){
    // use the Stripe or Braintree credit card form validator and any other form validations you want here
    // Braintree: https://github.com/braintree/card-validator
    // Stripe: https://github.com/stripe/jquery.payment
    // return a string value of the problem
    return '';
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('FORM#checkout').append('<input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" />');
    var clientToken = 'sandbox_555555_555555555555555';
    braintree.setup(clientToken, 'custom', {
        id:'checkout',
        onPaymentMethodReceived: function (paymentMethod) { // Braintree's docs fail to mention this happens only on a form submit
            $('#btnPurchase').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled');
            var sErr = invalidForm();
            if (sErr) {
                alert(sErr); // obviously do something better than this
                $('#btnPurchase').removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
                return false;
            } // else...
            $('#token').val(paymentMethod.nonce);
            $('FORM#checkout').submit();
            return true;
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

Now on the receiving end of your form post, you can process a `$_POST['token']` instead of `$_POST['payment_method_nonce']` but it's the same thing, just named differently. Note that you shouldn't change the field name to 'payment_method_nonce' because for some odd reason the Braintree API erases the value!

Note in your question -- you had it wrong because you were going to submit the form without client-side card validation. So, see the comment above and use either the Stripe or Braintree Javascript code that validates a credit card.

Note that your credit card form must not have "name" attributes on these fields: Cardholder Name, Credit Card Number, Expiration Date (MM/YY), or CVV/CVC. If you did, then you will require PCI compliance, which is a pain. Instead, you must use these attributes on those fields.

```
data-braintree-name="cardholder_name"
data-braintree-name="number"
data-braintree-name="expiration_date"
data-braintree-name="cvv"
```

On the server, you then do the charge like the following. My example below requires you to change it as necessary, such as receiving $_POST fields for name, email, phon, billing, and shipping instead of hard-coding them:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$sToken = @ $_POST['token'];

require_once('braintree/lib/Braintree.php');

// modify if going live
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
// change the next three per your configuration
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('4444hjxm5h27zxdb');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('444443c8qcf2wq5p');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('4444b76e4bbf8a6f03cb7ace0e812ba');

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(
  [
    'paymentMethodNonce' => $sToken,
    'amount' => '100.00', // currency not required because it's determined by the merchant account settings
    'customer' => [
        'firstName' => 'John',
        'lastName' => 'Doe',
        'phone' => '614-111-2222',
        'email' => 'example@example.com'
    ],
    'billing' => [
        'firstName' => 'John',
        'lastName' => 'Doe',
        'streetAddress' => '100 Main Street',
        'extendedAddress' => 'Apt A',
        'locality' => 'Columbus',
        'region' => 'OH',
        'postalCode' => '43085',
        'countryCodeAlpha2' => 'US'
    ],
    'shipping' => [
        'firstName' => 'John',
        'lastName' => 'Doe',
        'streetAddress' => '100 Main Street',
        'extendedAddress' => 'Apt A',
        'locality' => 'Columbus',
        'region' => 'OH',
        'postalCode' => '43085',
        'countryCodeAlpha2' => 'US'
    ],
    'options' => [
        'submitForSettlement' => TRUE
    ]
  ]
);

print_r($result);
```